# Unable to convert JSON file to CSV using Python

Tags: python, json, csv, python-3.x, pandas

I was trying to convert the below JSON file into a csv file.

JSON file

```
[{
"SubmitID":1, "Worksheet":3, "UserID":65,
 "Q1":"395",
 "Q2":"2178",
 "Q3":"2699",
 "Q4":"1494"},{
 "SubmitID":2, "Worksheet":3, "UserID":65,
  "Q4":"1394"},{
 "SubmitID":3, "Worksheet":4, "UserID":65,
  "Q1":"1629",
  "Q2":"1950",
  "Q3":"0117",
  "Q4":"1816",
 "Empty":" "}]
```

However, my Python code below gives the error message "TypeError: Expected String or Unicode". May I know how should I modify my program to make it work?

```
import json
import pandas as pd

f2 = open('temp.json')
useful_input = json.load(f2)
df=pd.read_json(useful_input)
print(df)
df.to_csv('results.csv')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to pass the address string to `pd.read_json()`:

```
df=pd.read_json("temp.json")
```

Answer (score 4):

You have not to use json module:

Try:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_json("temp.json")
print(df)
df.to_csv('results.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('data.json')
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False, columns=['title', 'subtitle', 'date', 'description'])

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df = df[df.columns[:4]]
df.dropna(how='all')
df.to_json('data.json', orient='records')
```